# AngularJS grabbing attributes value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say I have

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div minicalendar>
        <div class="actions">
            <span ng-click="change()" month="2" year="2014">Prev</span>
            <span ng-click="change()" month="4" year="2014">Next</span>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I currently have the following directive:

```
var App = angular.module('myApp', [] );
App.directive('minicalendar', function() {
   return {
       controller: function($scope, $http) {
           $scope.change = function() {
               // use $http and pass the month and year
           }
      }
   }
});
```

How can I grab the month and year attribute values and send them via $http? This way I don't need to have a function prev() and another function called next() and can then just use one function change().

---

I ended up taking a different approach, which made it much easier:

```
<span ng-click="change(2, 2014)">Prev</span>
<span ng-click="change(4, 2014)">Next</span>
```

Now I can just call the function `change(month, year)` and get the parameters as I please.

Comment: You should be using an AngularJs ng-model right?

Comment: I think ng-model is for input, select, textarea etc. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your `minicalendar` directive in Angular's classical fashion, you should not store data on DOM elements and attributes directly, but use model (`$scope`) of the directive instead. Besides of it, it is better to incapsulate all the directive's logic inside of it, instead of relaying on the fact that correct markup (that "knows" that it runs in directive's scope and there is a `change()` function in directive's controller) is placed inside of directive when it is used. Here is an example of how it may be done:

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/T9grZk2gHHF4eGMkzXrq?p=info

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-init="currentDate = {month:3, year:2014}">
  <div minicalendar="currentDate">
    Some data
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).
  directive('minicalendar', function() {

    function getAnotherMonth(date, monthDelta) {
      // In Date() month starts from 0, so we should add and substract 1 when manipulating dates
      var other = new Date(date.year, date.month + monthDelta - 1);
      return {
        month: other.getMonth() + 1,
        year: other.getFullYear()
      }
    }

    return {
      template: '<div class="actions">' +
                  '<span ng-click="change(prev)">{{prev.label}}</span>' +
                  '<span ng-click="change(next)">{{next.label}}</span>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<h3>{{minicalendar.month}}-{{minicalendar.year}}</h3>' +
                '<div ng-transclude></div>',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        minicalendar: '=' // <= Bind your local scope minicalendar property to some external scope property passed in minicalendar attribute of directive's root element
      },
      link: function($scope) {
        $scope.$watch('minicalendar.month', function() {
          var prev = getAnotherMonth($scope.minicalendar, -1),
              next = getAnotherMonth($scope.minicalendar, +1);
          angular.extend($scope, {
            prev: {
              label: $scope.minicalendar.prev || 'Prev',
              month: prev.month,
              year: prev.year
            },
            next: {
              label: $scope.minicalendar.next || 'Next',
              month: next.month,
              year: next.year
            }
          });
        });
      },
      controller: ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.change = function(date) {
          $scope.minicalendar.month = date.month;
          $scope.minicalendar.year = date.year;
          // Do whatever you want with $http
        }
      }]
    }
  });
```

More info about writing custom directives you can find [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile).

Answer (score 0):

You could use hidden input fields. In addition this allows you to set the values in the controller.

**View Code**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div minicalendar>
        <div class="actions">
            <span ng-click="change()">
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="previous_month"/>
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="previous_year"/>
                Prev
            </span>
            <span ng-click="change()">
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="next_month"/>
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="next_year"/>
                Next
            </span>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**In Controller:**

```
$scope.previous_month = 2;
$scope.previous_year = 2014;

$scope.next_month = 4;
$scope.next_year = 2014;
```

Answer (score 0):

For get value of month/year, for this requirement, I assume you are using JQuery, then you can get it via the follow method:

- Add an id attribute to the prev and next span, for example

  `<span id='prevlink' ng-click="change()" month="2" year="2014">Prev</span>
  <span id='nextlink' ng-click="change()" month="4" year="2014">Next</span>`
- Then you can get value of month/year via

  `prevmonth = $("#prevlink").attr('month')
  prevyear  = $("#prevlink").attr('year')
  nextmonth = $("#nextlink").attr('month')
  nextmonth = $("#nextlink").attr('year')`

If you are not using jQuery, then you can do this by this method:

- First change definition of the controller to

  `controller: function($scope, $element, $http) {`
- Then get values via

  `$element[0].childNodes[1].attributes['month'].value;
  $element[0].childNodes[1].attributes['year'].value;
  $element[0].childNodes[3].attributes['month'].value;
  $element[0].childNodes[3].attributes['year'].value;`

Notice:

this code fragment works exactly for what you posted above, if you adjusted structure of the html elements, you will need to change the indexes for the child nodes.